# HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found IIS 7.5 for Coldfusion files

Tags: iis, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

When I call mydomain.com/images/test.jpg I see the pic fine but then if I do mydomain.com/index.cfm

I get the following[image]

Also I've make sure that in IIS Handler Mappings I've put cfm and cfc.  Anything else I forgot?

Running: IIS 7.5, 
windows 2008,
Coldfusion 9,
cfwheels

I've remote web.config and now I get
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ran `c:\ColdFusion9\bin\connectors\IIS_connector.bat` and everything worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

From the look of the 404 error it is saying that you are ending up at /rewrite.cfm/index.cfm.  I am going to bet that is what is wrong.  Can we have some more information about what the application is?  It looks like there is an issue with your routing within the application, not with IIS

Comment: Using cfwheels framework...I've removed the web.config and now I get Error 500

Comment: It you put the web.config back and remove the CFWheels app, but leave a simple Hello World index.cfm file does it work?